# How to extract email addresses in excel?

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with 40,000 twitter user bios and want to extract email addresses into separate column. What's the best way to do this in excel? I've done this in google sheets using regex but is there an equivalent to REGEX in excel that will extract the email addresses?

Thank you for your time and help,

Matt

Comment: [Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)! Please take a look on how to [ask questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it will enhance your chances to receive appropriate help from the community.

Comment: Yes there is. But you need to write a VBA User Defined Function. Plenty of information on this site for you to research and try out.  You can also do it with string functions. Again, there are plenty of examples as to how to do it.

Comment: You can use `RegEx`, but with 40K records `RegEx` sometime can be time costy, you can most likely get away with other `Text` functions like `Instr` and `Mid`

Comment: @ronrosenfield Awesome, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @shairado Thank you so much for your response, I will look into this. I appreciate your help